# I'm having a problem with the second light in a series of two blinking rather than staying constantly lit

Tags: electrical

Over a year ago, I installed a number of recessed ceiling lights replacing existing lights.  All of a sudden, the second light in a series of two started flashing rather than staying constantly on.   I have rewired that light. I have rewired the first light in the series and thus the series. I have changed the second light fixture. No matter what I have done I get the same result. What is really strange is that this just started happening after a year. It also is not happening any where else in the house where I have put similar installs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Type of light bulbs?  When changing the second fixture did you also change the bulb or is it built in?

Comment: Thermal limiter/cutout is a typical reason for this behavior. Location getting hotter for some reason, bulb higher wattage than advised, etc.

Comment: Have you tried switching the fixtures around?  If the second fixture works good in first place, then it is the cable or the heat.

Comment: More information please. Are they sealed fixtures? Do you have separate drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once after installing recessed can lights.  The fixtures have a temperature sensor in them that will shut off the light if the temperature gets too hot.  Without this, the metal fixture can get hot enough to be a fire hazard.

Here's a couple of things to check:

- Is the light bulb you're using listed as being suitable for use in recessed/enclosed fixtures?  Some bulbs require lots of circulating air to cool themselves, especially those LEDs that have the heavy metal heatsinks.
- Is the recessed light fixture IC-rated?  This means that it's designed to be used with the can in contact with (or in close proximity to) the insulation in your ceiling.  Fixtures that are not IC rated typically need open space above them for air to circulate and keep them cool.  Otherwise, they can get hot enough to risk igniting certain types of insulation.
- Does the fixture have/need a heat shield?  Some fixtures have a shield/reflector behind the socket that reflects light back into the room and reduces the amount that ends up going up into the fixture and attic as heat.  Similarly, some fixtures have the socket mounted on a slide.  Sliding it farther towards the opening will move your heat source farther away from your temperature sensor.
- Do these fixtures have lenses over the front, or are they open?  Lenses block most of your airflow.  Running the fixture with the lens off is an easy test.

I diagnosed my heat problem by standing on a ladder and holding a strong fan up to the flickering light.  After several minutes of aggressive direct cooling, the flickering stopped.  For me, the solution ended up being to slide the bulb socket out about an inch and give the back side of the fixture more room to breathe.